# CSS3 flip animation not working in ie10/11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I'm trying to create a flip animation hover with css3, but it's not working in IE10/IE11

The backside/backface of the tile is not showing when hovered? Works fine in any other browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a fiddle of the animation:

```
( http://jsfiddle.net/Alekyeye/LzKB2/ )
```